# How to listen to changes in a firestore document when doc id is unknown

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

Just a FYI; I have checked all the previously asked questions and none of them relate directly to my problem. I have documents in a collection and i’m trying to listen to changes to the documents. I am first using `get()` to retrieve all the documents in the collection and then looping through all of them to listen to changes. This might be the wrong way to do this but i couldn't find anything else in the docs or online.

My problem is that because i’m using `get()` first, the onSnapshot listener isn't getting invoked unless i manually refresh. I’m trying to get it to show changes automatically as they happen. For example, if i add a document to the collection i expect it to run.

Here's my code:

```
const db = firestore().collection('Networks');

const NetworksListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({ networks: [] });

    const { networks } = state;

    const getNetworks = async () => {
        try {
            await db.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                let networks = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    db.doc(doc.id).onSnapshot(newDoc => {
                        console.log(newDoc.id, '=====>', newDoc.data());
                        networks.push(doc.data());
                    });
                });
                setState({
                    networks: networks
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getNetworks();

    }, []);
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be far easier for you to instead use [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) on the entire collection (a CollectionReference is a Query that finds all documents).  The snapshot you receive will contain information about each document that changed (added, changed, or removed) since the last time your listener was called.

```
firestore().collection('Networks').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    // handle changes to documents in the collection here
})
```

Comment: with `unsubscribe`
---------

`
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firestore().collection('Networks').onSnapshot((snap) => {
    // handle changes to documents in the collection here
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
`